# Perl - print out numbers without decimal point

Tags: perl, decimal

Is there anyway to have perl run through a file of numbers and print out only the numbers that don't have a decimal point in them?

So lets say I have 60, 78.9, 109 and I want it to print out 60, 109.

Is this possible in Perl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`3.0` and `3` is the same number, so you can only check for a decimal point if you have string representations of numbers. If that's what you have, you can use the following:

```
print "$_\n" for grep { !/\./ } @numbers;
   -or-
print "$_\n" for grep { /^[0-9]+\z/ } @numbers;
```

If, on the other hand, you want to filter out numbers with a fractional component (three, but three and one tenth shouldn't), then you can check if `int` changes the number at all (since it removes the fractional component).

```
print "$_\n" for grep { $_ == int($_) } @numbers;
```

Comment: ok I just barely undestand what you're talking about and know nothing about the "grep" function. How do I tell if my numbers are in strings or fractional components? I just have them in a text file

Comment: They'll be text in the file, so you have option of using either depending on what you want do about `3.0`. Feel free to use a different kind of loop if you don't want to use `grep`. The relevant part is `$_ !~ /\./` and `$_==int($_)`.

Comment: `grep { m/^\d+$/ } @numbers` seems more straightforward, and more correct. For instance what if numbers happened to contain `"abc"`. (for the first case, your second example is great)

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -ne 'print unless /\./;' < file
```

is the simplest way to do what you describe with Perl that I can think of.

Comment: `perl` is a the Perl interpreter. `-n` executes the script for reach line of the files provided as arguments (or STDIN if no arguments are provided). `-e` allows one to provide the script to execute as a parameter rather than storing it in a file. [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html).